# forEach takes an array and a callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback

I need help for this problem because I don't understand it :(. Please help!

The function forEach takes an array and a callback. It runs the callback on each element of the array - and that's it!

```
var alphabet = '';
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
forEach(letters, function(char) {
  alphabet += char;
});
console.log(alphabet);   //prints 'abcd'


**(underneath is is where I edit)**



// Challenge 4
function forEach(array, callback) {

}

// see for yourself if your forEach works!
```

Comment: Maybe put up an example of what you have tried to do or where you are getting stuck.

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? Do you know how to loop through an array? Do you know how to call a function, and how to supply arguments to a function? Do you not understand the fundamental principle of the question (i.e., you simply don't understand one or more of the words used in the instructions, "run the callback on each element of the array")? I assume from the text "Challenge 4" that the code present in your question is boilerplate that you didn't write yourself, so I have no idea what you know and don't know.

Comment: whats your expected output given a particular input?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly what you want to achieve, but your code is not idiomatic JavaScript...

The core JavaScript language already provides a `forEach` method that you can use directly. Please read the following page: [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

When you use `forEach`, your code should look like this:

```
var alphabet = '',
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

letters.forEach(function (letter) {
  alphabet += letter;
});

console.log(alphabet);
```

But if you are concerned about performance leaks, you may want to use a traditional `for` loop with cached length instead.

```
var alphabet = '',
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

for(var i = 0, len = letters.length; i < len; i++) {
  alphabet += letters[i];
}

console.log(alphabet);
```

Thanks to ES6, you can also use the `for...of` loop on iterable objects like arrays. This is the recommended instruction in modern JavaScript applications:

```
let alphabet = '',
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

for (const letter of letters) {
  alphabet += letter;
}

console.log(alphabet);
```

But since developers are lazy sometimes, the best answer is probably this one:

```
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    alphabet = letters.join('');

console.log(alphabet);
```